# Want React to ignore the style attribute

Tags: reactjs

I understand that the React way of specifying styles is

```
<div style={{width:"100%"}}></div>
```

When I specify

```
<div style='width:"100%'></div>
```

I get an error.

Is there any way of asking React to ignore the style attribute and use it as it is - a string?

What I want is for React to treat the style attribute as a string. So I want to specify the style like any other data- attribute.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear enough - if you will explain what your goal is, in this case, it will be easier to help you

Comment: Apolgogies if I was not clear @ErezLieberman. Have edited the question. When I specify data- attribute, like data-field="abcd", the attribute is transpiled as a string. I want React to treat the style attribute as a string and not as an object. Is there a way I can ask React to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted that styling to apply in certain conditions, then you could use a conditional statement inside curly brackets. But either way, React won't recognize that styling unless it's inside curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

According to React documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style):

> The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string.

There's no native way of doing that in ReactJS.